# Register Custom Protocol with WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am accessing a web server that requires a custom protocol rather than http in the url. I have tried to register my protocol, but there isn't much documentation on how to get this to work. The web server serves up standard HTTP responses, but if the request isn't prepended with custom:// instead of http://, it won't work. I would like to just use the WebRequest underlying functionality as is since this is ultimately HTTP, however, I need a way to submit the request with my custom protocol url. I register it like this:

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("custom", new CustomWebRequestCreator());
```

But then, when I go to create a WebRequest, while it returns my custom class after this code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("custom://192.168.0.122:94934/resource");
System.Net.WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

The debugger says that the request is actually my custom class, but then I get this exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467263
  Message=This method is not implemented by this class.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebRequest.GetResponse()
...
```

When I try to just pass my URL to WebRequest.Create() without registering the prefix, I get this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=The URI prefix is not recognized.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
       at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   ...
```

Any idea how I might get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible, or would be reaching the level of complexity of re-implementing HTTP for WebRequest from scratch.

I suggest you instead create a TCP relay, which you connect to using WebRequest [http://localhost/resource], in order to make it work without trying to contort WebRequest. The relay would in turn forward to TCP socket 192.168.0.122:94934.

With a relay, you use the common and simplified WebRequest object. If it's for a console/webforms applicaiton, the relay can be started on another thread (or can be started asynchronously), when the application is started.